# How to Control Backlight and Set Max Limit Brightness in Display of Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, display, brightness, intel, macbook

My Macbook Air 2013 power lasts 1.5 hours with just too bright light. More than 7 hours with normal light (that is 30-40% of the current max) corresponding to my default brightness in OS X where the battery lasts 7-9 hours. 
I would like to have a one-liner of `gsettings` to make the change. 
There is a rapid jump in power consumption of display depending on the setting. I would like to find the optimum one for power consumption and usability.

- Feature request https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=67454, pointed out here https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Apple/MacBookAir/6-2. No upstread fix uploaded yet. It is not a bug but there is missing completely *non-i915 backlight control*, it is ranked medium majority importance but it is decided as *notourbug*. Possible change of hardware soon.
- Any workarounds about the backlight?

I do

```
git clone https://github.com/patjak/mba6x_bl
Cloning into 'mba6x_bl'...
remote: Counting objects: 140, done.
remote: Total 140 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 140
Receiving objects: 100% (140/140), 45.12 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (76/76), done.
Checking connectivity... done.

masi@masi:~/jacob$ cd mba6x_bl/

masi@masi:~/jacob/mba6x_bl$ make
make -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-22-generic/build M=/home/masi/jacob/mba6x_bl modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-22-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/masi/jacob/mba6x_bl/mba6x_bl.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /home/masi/jacob/mba6x_bl/mba6x_bl.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/masi/jacob/mba6x_bl/mba6x_bl.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-22-generic'

masi@masi:~/jacob/mba6x_bl$ sudo make install
make -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-22-generic/build M=/home/masi/jacob/mba6x_bl modules_install
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-22-generic'
  INSTALL /home/masi/jacob/mba6x_bl/mba6x_bl.ko
At main.c:222:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
  DEPMOD  4.4.0-22-generic
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-22-generic'
```

where the errors are harmless. The result works in my system! 
[Here](https://github.com/patjak/mba6x_bl/issues/46) is a ticket about the case.

- Source: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=67454

Laptop: Macbook Air 2013-mid (6.2)
Ubuntu versions: 16.04
Linux kernel: 4.4 and 4.6
Status: *deprecated feature [request](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=67454) (RESOLVED NOTOURBUG) because no resources for the development* for the adjustment of Apple Hardware for Linux at least on the Intel side. However, Patrik Jacobsen is working with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do which works in most cases of Macbook 6.2

```
git clone https://github.com/patjak/mba6x_bl && cd mba6x_bl/ && make && make install
```

The errors about SSL are harmless.

- Source: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=67454

---

Answer (score 1):

I can't get *gsettings* to change the brightness on my laptop running Ubuntu 16.06, but I can change the brightness by storing a value in /sys/class/backlight/device-name/brightness where device-name is one of the video devices listed in /sys/class/backlight.  In each of these directories there is a max_brightness file. To write to these files you will need to be root.  So in my case, using the first of the 3 device directories (which in my case is acpi_video0),

```
$ ls /sys/class/backlight    # shows the video devices
acpi_video0    acpi_video1    radeon_bl0
$ cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness   # shows current level
7
$ cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness   # shows max level
10
$ sudo sh   # become super-user
# echo 3 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness   # dim screen
# echo 10 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness   # max brightness
# exit   # return to unprivileged user
$ sudo sh -c "echo 10 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness"
```

The final line above gives a "one-liner" brightness change command.

You could extend this if desired to compute a fraction of brightness required based on max_brightness using the *expr* command.

P.S. My laptop is an Intel Compaq CQ62 so this may not solve the problem on a Macbook.

Comment: How can you set the brightness to 30% of the default value? Is it `sudo sh -c "echo 3 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness"`?

Comment: Yes, that works on my laptop but if you don't have an acpi_video0 directory you'll have to adapt the command accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I have the same directory in 16.04. The value changes there dynamically when you make changes in your keyboard. It would be great to scale this value always like by 1/2. I think you cannot do it with the file itself. There has to be something by which you can control it dynamically. I do not understand the fine details enough for the answer.

Comment: Try reading (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight) for general info on Linux backlight approaches.  You may be able to install and use xbacklight to set a 50% value, but I don't see a way of changing the maximum (so scaling as you wish).

Comment: Can `systemd-backlight` handle such a permanent scaling to 50%? Let the user have the scaling normally but all his/her values are scaled by 50%.