# How to enable wl option of broadcom-sta-dkms?

Tags: wireless, 16.04, broadcom, macbook

Package https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=broadcom-sta-dkms and its option `wl` are proposed as the fix for Macbook Air 2013-mid (6.2) [here](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Apple/MacBookAir/6-2), also in Ubuntu, since they work in the upstream. 
I want to know how to enable the option.

- Without `wl` option of `broadcom-sta-dkms`, the lid closure will halt wifi connection. New connections cannot be made. Only solution is restart.
- With `Broadcom BCM4360`, the firmware `firmware-b43-installer` is not sufficient.

Ubuntu versions: 14.04 and 16.04
Laptop: Macbook 6.2

Comment: In Ubuntu, you would simply do: `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source` If you have the 4360 device, I doubt it it supported prior to Ubuntu 16.04. We know nothing about Debian; it is off-topic here.

Comment: The Broadcom driver is maintained by Intel??

Comment: I am sorry. I don't understand what at all this has to do with your Broadcom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do

```
% See https://wiki.debian.org/wl
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted contrib non-free
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted contrib non-free

% unload conflicting modules
modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma
modprobe wl
```

which works if there is no conflict with PatrikJacobsen's fix described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/784494/25388) i.e. backlight.
If it works as expected, the wifi also works as expected. I have noticed unstable powerconfigurations also with the complications of the *non-i915 backlight control* in Macbook Air 2013-mid.